# Choosing permutations with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have to choose $k$ items out of $n$ choices, and my selection needs to be in the correct order (i.e. permutation, not combination). After I make a choice, I receive a hint that tells me how many of my selections were correct, and how many were in the correct order.

For example, if I'm trying to choose $k = 4$ out of $n = 6$ items, and the correct ordered set is $\{5, 3, 1, 2\}$, then an exchange may go as follows:

```
0,1,2,3
(3, 0) # 3 correct, 0 in the correct position

0,1,2,5
(3, 0)

0,1,5,3
(3, 0)

0,5,2,3
(3,0)

5,1,2,3
(4,1)

5,3,1,2
(4,4)

-> correct order, the game is over
```

The problem is I'm only given a limited number of tries to get the order right, so if $n = 6, k = 4$, then I only get $t = 6$ tries, if $n = 10, k = 5$ then $t = 5$, and if $n = 35, k = 6$ then $t = 18$.

**Where do I start to even solve this?** It almost seems like a constraint solving problem. The hard part seems to be that I only know something for sure if I only change 1 thing at once, but the upper bound on that is way more than the number of tries I get.

Comment: If the no. of tries given is small, there may be no way to actually solve it(unless you're lucky).

Comment: $t=5, n=10, k=5$ sounds awfully tight, but the others should be quite feasible with a basic strategy.  Think of it as similar to binary search, where each guess allows you to throw out a certain fraction of the number of possibilities.  You might find inspiration in Knuth's algorithm for a [very similar game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Algorithms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game is called MasterMind.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29